# DataMatrix barcode size remains the same regardless of the payload

Tags: barcode

I'd like to use DataMatrix (EC 200) barcodes to label some items.

There are always N bytes of data. Can I assume that the minimal barcode size remains the same regardless of the given data?
So there is no difference in the minimal size of the barcode even if there are just N bytes of random data?

If there is not such a minimal size: How big do I have to make my barcodes to be sure that the size will fit every possible data stream of the given length N?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are encoding bytes, then I assume you are using Base 256 encodation, as the Data Matrix spec calls it. In this encodation each input byte produces one encoded byte exactly. So, yes, any n bytes will require the same number of encoded bytes, and that in turn means that you will require the same dimension (size) barcode, yes.